# Iteração de DF's no pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Fala galera.
Supondo que eu tenha um df1 só com uma coluna de ID, e outro df2 com informações q eu quero cadastrar nesse df1. Porém eu preciso q cada id do df1 repita para todas as informações do df2

Por exemplo.

df1= [1, 2, 3, 4]

df2= [info1, info2, info3]

df_final = [ 1 -> info1, 1-> info2, 1->info3 ... 4->info3]

Estou tentando fazer um for, dentro de outro for.
Criei um id auxiliar para o df2 para que isso fosse feito, porém não consigo o resultado esperado, apesar da logíca eu acreditar q está correta.

```
for id1, row in df1.iterrows():
   for id2, row in df2.iterrows():
      df1[colunadeinformações] = df2[colunadeinformações]
```

Tem alguma função que vocês possam me recomendar o estudo para que eu consigo algo parecido com o exposto ?
desde já agradeço.

Comment: Veja isso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744050/1452488

Comment: Nossa, perfeito! Obrigado. Quantos for em vão eu tentei. rs.